# Adding Drag & Drop to Backbone Todos with jQuery/UI

Tags: backbone.js, drag-and-drop

I'm totally new to backbone.js and have just started delving into the infamous 'todos' app to get a feel for it. I've noticed that [localtodos.com](http://localtodos.com/) includes a nice drag & drop functionality whereas [the backbone example](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html) doesn't. The localtodos drag & drop is implemented with Mootools however and I'm looking to use jQuery and jQuery UI instead.

I came across [an example which looked to have already implemented it](http://jonahlyn.heroku.com/blog/2011/12/02/backbone-drag-and-drop) but when I've tried it there's a problem with the data-id attribute. Adding:

```
<%= id ? 'data-id="'+id+'"' : '' %>
```

to the template prevents me from entering any todo items. I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined

But with the drag and drop implementation included in the initialize function of the AppView template does allow for drag and drop:

```
this.$("#todo-list").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        $('div.todo',this).each(function(i) {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id'),
                todo = Todos.get(id);
            todo.save({order: i + 1});
        });
    }
});
```

If I remove the data-id attribute code then I can enter todo items again but when I refresh the page their order isn't saved (obviously).

I just can't figure out what the problem is with the data-id attribute. A more complete example of the code I'm working with is available as [gist here](https://gist.github.com/2761530).

Comment: Does the Gist contain your code? it seems to have views, backbone.js code and styles. Please add the view code to your question. the view you have created using `Backbone.View.extend`

Comment: did you go through this fiddle. It does exactly as you wanted to http://jsfiddle.net/jonahlyn/xYP4F/

Comment: Woops, sorry, I copied the wrong js file. I've  updated the gist with the todos.js file contents now. The BB View is in there. Yes, I've also taken a look at that gist and even tried copying and pasting it directly but I get the same result. That's what I'm a little confused about. I'm not sure if it's a slight difference in jsFiddle or maybe my dependencies/load order/etc? I have checked all are getting loaded and in what I believe to be the correct order. It could very well be something small.

Comment: Why don;t you copy and paste the exact Jsfiddle mentioned into separate html file and try it without any extras you have. If it works something is wrong on your part or code

Comment: After copying *everything* across exactly, including the dependencies,  it seems to be backbone.js which is the problem. The version linked in the fiddle is 0.5.3 - that works fine. If you update backbone to the latest version (0.9.2) errors occur when trying to add a new item. Specifically the error is : "Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined". Any ideas what would have fundamentally changed in backbone in that time to cause that error?